# Proper way to assign data to a subset of a multiindexed pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Take the dataframe, `di`,  created by:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Event": ['Biathlon', 'Ski Jump', 'Slalom', 'Downhill'],
    "Award": ['Gold', 'Bronze', 'Gold', 'Silver'],
    "Points":  ['100', '10', '100', '40'],
    "Rank":   ['1', '3', '1', '2']
}

d = pd.DataFrame(data)
di = d.set_index(["Award","Event"])
print(di)
```

What would the be the proper way to change the points value for the `('Bronze', 'Ski Jump')` record?

Through trial and error, I know that the following seems to work, though it's not clear to me from the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) that this is an accepted approach.

```
di.loc[('Bronze', 'Ski Jump'), 'Points'] = 20
```

So how would you handle this? Can you point me toward the relevant documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it right. From the [indexing docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) (emphasis mine):

> `.loc` is primarily **label based**, but may also be used with a boolean array.

When using `.loc` on a `DataFrame`, the syntax is

> `df.loc[row_indexer,column_indexer]`

Each of `row_indexer` and `column_indexer` can be

> - **A single label** [...]
> - A list or array of labels `['a', 'b', 'c']`
> - A slice object with labels `'a':'f'` [...]
> - A boolean array

You are using the first bullet point. Your row index is a multi-index, for which labels are tuples. Your column index is a plain string index. Then, the expression

```
di.loc[('Bronze', 'Ski Jump'), 'Points']
```

translates to "get the value located at `('Bronze', 'Ski Jump')` along the row multi-index and at `'Points'` along the column index." This is precisely what you wanted.

---

Another way to think about this example is to forget the multi-index. From [MultiIndex / Advanced Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html):

> It's worth keeping in mind that there's **nothing preventing you from using tuples as atomic labels on an axis**.

A multi-index is very similar to a plain tuple index, although it provides extended functionality (e.g. you can index using only the first level like `di.loc['Bronze']`). Nevertheless, you can actually create your data frame like

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['100', '1'],
    ['10', '3'],
    ['100', '1'],
    ['40', '2']
], columns=['Points', 'Rank'], index=[
    ('Gold', 'Biathlon'),
    ('Bronze', 'Ski Jump'),
    ('Gold', 'Slalom'),
    ('Silver', 'Downhill')
])
```

This makes it more apparent why `di.loc[('Bronze', 'Ski Jump'), 'Points']` is a valid label selection.